# Can't transform Linq to IEnumerable

Tags: .net, linq, ienumerable

I have this method on my DAL class:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {              
            var _ped = 
                from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
                where Pedidos.ID_Cliente == 1
                select new {Pedidos.ID_Pedido, Pedidos.Fecha, Pedidos.Clientes};
            return _ped.ToList();
        }
    }
```

And VS give this error:

```
    Error   3   No se puede convertir implícitamente el 
tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' 
en 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Ohmio.ModelLayer.Pedidos>'. 
Ya existe una conversión explícita (compruebe si le falta una conversión)
```

What i'm I doing wrong here?Thanks

**EDIT**
More info: Pedidos is defined as POCOs db class
So This work just fine:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
        {
            using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
            {
                return context.Pedidos.ToList();
            }
        }
```

But i need to use linq to select just some field and a where clause.
When I try this as suggested:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
        {
            using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
            {              
                var _ped = 
                    from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
                    where Pedidos.ID_Cliente == 1
                    select new Pedidos {Pedidos.ID_Pedido, Pedidos.Fecha, Pedidos.Clientes};
                return _ped.ToList();
            }
        }
```

I get this error:

```
    Can't inicialize type 'Ohmio.ModelLayer.Pedidos' with a colection inicializer because 
don't implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' (Manual translate)
```

I'm i missing something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the type you said you would. You're returning an anonymous type. Fix this by projecting into the known type:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {              
            var _ped = 
                from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
                where Pedidos.ID_Cliente == 1
                select new Pedidos {Id = Pedidos.ID_Pedido, Fecha = Pedidos.Fecha, Clientes = Pedidos.Clientes};
            return _ped.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Or if you don't need the projection and are returning the EF model directly:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {              
            var _ped = 
                from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
                where Pedidos.ID_Cliente == 1
                select Pedidos;
            return _ped.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Or simply:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
    {
        using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
        {              
            return context.Pedidos.Where(p => p.ID_Cliente == 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Options 1 and 2 give the error i mention. thrid option Works but i need to select specific fields. Any idea?

Comment: Create a separate DTO to project into rather than using the entity class itself. You have more code to maintain, but add an abstraction layer which may be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a list of *anonymous objects*.If you want a strongly-typed collection change your code like this:

```
 var _ped = from p in context.Pedidos
            where p.ID_Cliente == 1
            select new Pedidos 
            {
                ID_Pedido = p.ID_Pedido, 
                Fecha = p.Fecha, 
                Clientes = p.Clientes
            };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try this and now i get: No se puede inicializar el tipo 'Ohmio.ModelLayer.Pedidos' con un inicializador de colección porque no implementa 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Pedidos IS a instance of a POCO DB object

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the language of the error.But if you set your properties correctly, you won't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
select Pedidos;
```

Instead of this:

```
select new {Pedidos.ID_Pedido, Pedidos.Fecha, Pedidos.Clientes};
```

---

If this is Linq-to-entites, you can't project to an entity class, so this **wouldn't** work:

```
select new Pedidos { ... }
```

However, you can project to a new class like

```
select new PedidosCustomClass { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` is selecting a new anonymous type, but you're trying to return that anonymous type as instances of `Pedidos`. You need to change your `select` to create instances of `Pedidos`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to return an collection of anonymous objects.

You'll need to name your object in your `select` to `Pedidos`:

```
select new Pedidos { ID_Pedido = Pedidos.Id_Pedido, 
                     Fecha     = Pedidos.Fecha, 
                     Clientes  = Pedidos.Clientes };
```

Comment: Thanks! I get this error: Can't inicialize type 'Ohmio.ModelLayer.Pedidos' with a colection inicializer because 
don't implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' (Manual translate)

Comment: You need to set the properties on your object as you would any new object. See my edited answer for how you should be able to fix it. Sorry, but I'm not that familiar with the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list of `anonymous` objects and then trying to return it as list of `Pedidos`. the compiler doesn't know how to do the casting. You can either change it to:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
{
    using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
    {              
        var _ped = 
            from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
            where Pedidos.ID_Cliente == 1
            select new Pedidos;
        return _ped.ToList();
    }
}
```

Or you will have to do the maping/casting yourself. Something like this will work:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
{
    using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
    {              
        var _ped = 
            from P in context.Pedidos
            where P.ID_Cliente == 1
            select new Pedidos { ID_Pedido = P.ID_Pedido,
                                 Fecha = P.Fecha,
                                 Clientes = P.Clientes};
        return _ped.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause of the original error you got already explained by @Selman22. But the solution causes another error because you can't create mapped entity (your *POCOs db class*) in LINQ-to-entity query. To *workaround* this, try to initialize the entity in client side (outside LINQ-to-entity query) :

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
{
    using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
    {              
        var _ped = 
            (   
                from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
                where Pedidos.ID_Cliente == 1
                select new {Pedidos.ID_Pedido, Pedidos.Fecha, Pedidos.Clientes}
            ).ToList();
        return _ped.Select(o => new Pedidos 
                                {
                                    ID_Pedido = p.ID_Pedido, 
                                    Fecha = p.Fecha, 
                                    Clientes = p.Clientes
                                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to instanciate new Pedidos?
Try simply this:

```
public IEnumerable<Pedidos> Pedidos_Listar()
{
    using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
    {              
        return context.Pedidos
            .Where(p => p.ID_Cliente == 1)
            .AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```